Prove $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{1}{2}$ with $ \varepsilon - \delta $ definition
$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{1}{2}$
Here is my attempt
Prep work:
$$\Bigl| \frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{2} \Bigr| = \frac{1}{2} \Bigl| \frac{1-x}{1+x}\Bigr|=\frac{1}{2}\cdot |x-1| \cdot \frac{1}{|1+x|}$$
If we assume $|x-1|< 1$ is true, it would follow $$ -1<x-1 \implies 1<x+1 \implies \frac{1}{|1+x|}<1$$ then we'd have $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot |x-1| \cdot \frac{1}{|1+x|} < \frac{1}{2}\cdot |x-1| \cdot 1 \quad (*)$$
This suggests a choice of $\delta = 2 \varepsilon$
Proof.
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and set $\delta = \min \{1, 2 \varepsilon \}$.
We assume $0<|x-1|<\delta$ which means $|x-1|<1 \land |x-1|<2 \varepsilon$
Then, by $(*)$ and $|x-1|<1$ indeed we have $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot |x-1| \cdot \frac{1}{|1+x|} < \frac{1}{2}\cdot |x-1| \cdot 1 $$
and by $|x-1|<2 \varepsilon$ $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot |x-1| < \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \varepsilon=\varepsilon$$
End of proof.
Is this correct, is it properly structured? thanks

Comments. (a) I don't really understand the sentence in what you call prep work which begins "Now if we" .. (b) I think that "prep work" is not part of the proof, so shouldn't be referenced in the proof: if you provide in the proof a line to justify $\frac{1}{|1+x|}<1$ whenever $|x-1|<1$ then it's all OK.

@ancientmathematician a) I meant "if we assume $|x-1|<1$ then it'd follow...", but sure I'll rephrase it. b) I would esentially repeat the same process as in prep work? I referenced it for brevity etc. but I get the point. thanks

My understanding of "prep work" may be wrong, I thought it meant "a bit of this and that trying to get a grip on the problem". And that any real maths started at "Proof". If you mean something else then ignore my remark (a). I still think that what you say doesn't prove the crucial inequality, I needed four lines to check it out.

@ancientmathematician "prep work" here is meant as in the usual work done prior to the $\varepsilon - \delta$ proofs. It's esentially working backwards, and I've seen it being referenced in the same manner as I did many times (I hope to be corrected if I'm mistaken here). I'll gladly provide the four lines you want. Although, if they are in prep work, I can write them out for you here in the comments, just to make sure we are on the same page about the part that needs to be rewritten within the proof-space

It's definitely correct and sufficient. Well done! 

If you want to be more clear, I'd repeat the first line of the prep work in the proof so that you're leading logically into the inequality.
